# How to format x-axis time scale values in Chart.js v4.2.1

Tags: javascript, chart.js, date-fns

I am not able to format the display format of Time. I am using chart.js v4.2.1 and date-fns v3.0.0(this as script from cdnjs).
I am able to get the unit but the display format I want is Day of a week day.Month (e.g: Mo 12.04, Tue 13.04, etc...)

Here is the code:

```
scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'need to be done'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: In date-fns version 2.x the format should be `EEE dd.MM`

Comment: @user2057925 , thanks a lot. That is correct , Please Write this as answer and I can mark it as Answered

Comment: @user2057925 if  possible can you suggest on zooming why it is not showing the hours, minutes and second as it is Time Cartisian Axis

Comment: added answer and some thoughts about zooming. Hopefully it helps you

Comment: @user2057925, yes I am using the chartjs-plugin-zoom, I am able to see the zoom  in chart but the x-label is not zooming to Hours, minute, second. Is this because I gave Unit as day ?

Comment: Yes, the zoom plugin doesn't change the scale config at that level (only min and max value). To change the unit, you should catch the zoom events and change the scale config accordingly with your logic.

Comment: have a look here if it can help https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/QWZyvZm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going thru the date-fns documentation (v2), the format string to use to have those date string representation is the following:

```
EEE dd.MM
```

HEre is the link to date-fns doc, about formatting: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format

About zooming, if you are using chartjs-plugin-zoom, it doesn't change the scale configuration and in your case the time unit.
But I think you can use the onComplete (or onProgress) hooks of the plugin to change the scale config at runtime, using your logic to change the time unit.